# Angular $window.scrollTo() isn't working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to scroll to a particular element after finding it on a page in my Angular app.

```
  angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    var foundDone = 0;
    var currOver = 0;
    for (var prog in $scope.programs){
      var big = $scope.programs[prog];
      if(!big.over && foundDone === 0){
        foundDone++;
        var e = document.getElementsByClassName('programThumbs')[currOver];
        var theTop = e.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        $window.scrollTo(0, theTop)
        console.log("Scrolled to " + theTop)
      }
      currOver++;
    }
  });
```

I've tried `$window.scrollTo()` as well as `window.scrollTo()`, but neither are doing anything here. My console logs: `Scrolled to 565`, which is the correct y-position.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have `jQuery` and [`jQuery.scrollTo`](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) installed?

Comment: jQuery is installed, yes. Not jQuery scrollTo - I'm just using the vanilla JS method. What actually seems to be happening is that it *is* scrolling, but then instantly snapping back up to the top of the page. There are no other scroll events in my code besides this.

Comment: Well, considering that native `scrollTo()` is still only a working draft... what browser are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about `scrollTo()` but have you tried [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) property?

> // Set the number of pixels scrolled
>
> element.scrollTop = intValue;